# Bug when unit testing Google Analytics tracker in XCode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-analytics

I'm writing a unit test to check that the string I pass to the `GAITracker` class is being returned as the `kGAIScreenName` property for each screen.

However when I try to pass a `sharedInstance` to the `GAI` class to initialize the `WNGoogleAnalyticsService` instance I am getting the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` as if it has not been allocated to the memory. No matter where I try to declare the sharedInstance won't initialize in the test class although it works fine in the `AppDelegate.m`.

WNGoogleAnlayticsServiceTest.m:

```
-(void)testIfNoScreenNameExists {
   NSString *screenName = @"Screen";
   Class builder = [GAIDictionaryBuilder class];
   GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];

WNGoogleAnalyticsService *s = [[WNGoogleAnalyticsService alloc] initWithGAInstance:gai
                                                             gaKey:@"test"
                                          gaDictionaryBuilderClass:builder
                                                         debugging:NO];

id<GAITracker> tracker = [s trackerForScreen:screenName];

XCTAssertEqualObjects([tracker get:kGAIScreenName], screenName); 
}
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
Add Google Analytics as analytics service
WNGoogleAnalyticsService *googleAnalyticsService = [[WNGoogleAnalyticsService alloc] initWithGAInstance:[GAI sharedInstance]
                                                                                                  gaKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"WNGoogleKey"]
                                                                               gaDictionaryBuilderClass:[GAIDictionaryBuilder class]
                                                                                              debugging:analyticsDebugging];
```

I'm at a loss as to how to even go about fixing this bug so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah I did actually, turns out I was trying to reuse a singleton by reusing the [GAI SharedInstance] method in both my WNGoogleAnlayticsServiceTest and in my AppDelegate which, by definition it cannot do. So if you want to test the Google Analytics methods you must use a tool like OCMock to do so and cannot initialise it twice.

Comment: If this works, you should write up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In line with the comment I left underneath my question, I feel I should formally answer this with my solution.

In the case of this unit test, I was trying to re-use a singleton by reusing the `[GAI SharedInstance]` method in both my WNGoogleAnlayticsServiceTest and in my AppDelegate.m file which, by definition, it cannot do.

So if you want to test the Google Analytics methods, you must use a tool like OCMock to do so as you can't initialise the sharedInstance twice.